# Python: Write 1,000,000 ints to file

Tags: python

What is the most compact way to write 1,000,000 ints (0, 1, 2...) to file using Python without zipping etc? My answer is: 1,000,000 * 3 bytes using struct module, but it seems like interviewer expected another answer...

Edit. Numbers from 1 to 1,000,000 in random order (so transform like 5, 6, 7 -> 5-7 can be applied in rare case). You can use any writing method you know, but the resulting file should have minimum size.

Comment: Write them how to the file? As cleartext, bytes...?

Comment: Nothing like a loaded interview question to expose the interviewer's ignorance.

Comment: Bobby, you can use any method you know, but the resulted file should have minimum size.

Comment: If that's the case, what do you mean by "without zipping etc."?

Comment: Tim Pietzcker, I mean that solution to write ints to the file and then archive that file using gzip, bzip etc is unacceptable.

Comment: @Vladimir: In that case, please add it to the question.

Comment: @Vladimir: Oh, are they sequential or random?

Comment: Bobby, numbers from 1 to 1,000,000 in random order.

Comment: @Vladimir: Sidenote: If you mention someone by name, write the @ in front of his name, so that he gets notified about follow-ups in the comments.

Comment: @Bobby, thanks, question is updated.

Comment: I guess you only need 20 bits, not 24.  That would reduce it from 3MB to 2.5MB.  Other than that, can you implement some form of compression in your code?

Comment: Can we zip before writing out the file?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, I guess no :)

Comment: @neil, thanks, I thought I can only write full bytes (8, 16, 24). Some form of compression can be implemented, but very basic. At interview I had to describe idea, not to write the code.

Comment: Compression wont help if the numbers are random.

Comment: 1000000 < 2**20, so it's possible to write it more compactly than 20 bits, but extracting the last 5% will take a lot more work.

Comment: Note that compression *does* help, because there's wasted bandwidth in the stream: there are values which are never used.  Deflate only gets about .5%, which is about a tenth of the 5% wasted space, but it gets that fairly consistently.

Comment: the question specifies 1,000,000 integers, but does not give any bounds on the values that those integers can take.

Comment: @Adrien Plisson, "Numbers from 1 to 1,000,000 in random order" is not enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your solution takes three bytes (= 24 bits) per integer. Theoretically, 20 bits are enough (since 2^19 < 1.000.000 < 2^20).

EDIT: Oops, just noticed Neil’s comment stating the same. I’m making this answer CW since it really belongs to him.

Comment: I am going to accept this, because @neil has come first with this idea. Can someone explain how to write 20 bits of int to file? struct module has not appropriate API for this...

Comment: @Vladimir: One way to do this with the `struct` module would be to take the numbers in pairs, shift one to left 20 bits and bitwise OR it with the other to get a 40 bit value. Then take that and split it up into 5 separate integers, b0 to b4, representing each byte of the value. This set of 5 small integers could then be converted to a 5 byte string using `struct.pack('bbbbb',b0,b1,b2,b3,b4)`.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, you can do A LOT better than 2.5MB, since not all orderings are possible.  One might argue that beating 5% would involve compression, since one is not storing the sequence itself.  Basically, you would want to store the canonical sequence number.  8 numbers from 0-7 in random order normally takes 24 bits (`log(8^8)/log(2)`), but with a canonical sequence number it would take 16 bits (`log(8!)/log(2)`).

Basically, this involves coming up with an algorithm which can translate any sequence of integers into a giant number.  Example of a possible numbering for 8 number sequence would be ordering by value:

```
01234567 : 0  
01234576 : 1  
01234657 : 2  
01234675 : 3  
01234756 : 4  
01234765 : 5  
...
```

The cost of this strategy is `log(1000000!)/log(2)` (i.e., `log_2(1000000!)`).
The standard solution usually costs about `log(1000000^1000000)/log(2)` .

You can also squeeze a tiny bit more space by treating `0000 0000 1111 1111` and `1111 1111` differently, but the amount of space saved by doing so is incredibly tiny.

**Edit:** A quick and dirty calculation indicates this optimization brings the size down to about 2.204MiB.

Due to the pigeonhole principle, I do not believe it is possible to do better than this strategy, regardless of whether you use compression or some other technique.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you do have to remember their order and that the numbers are in the range of 1 to 1,000,000, it would only take 20 bits or 2½ bytes to write each one since 1,000,000 is 0xF4240 in hexadecimal. You'd have to pack them together to not waste any space with this approach, but by doing so it would only take 2.5 * 1,000,000 bytes.

Comment: It's the best approach if you don't know anything else about the nunmbers and the order must be preserved.

Answer (score 1):

the question is clearly incomplete. here is my very compact attempt:

```
f = open('numbers.dat', 'w')
f.write('list(range(1,1000000))')
f.close()
```

loading the file:

```
f = open('numbers.dat', 'r')
numbers = eval(f.read().strip())
f.close()
```

that should do it.

*in fact, i don't see why 'python' is important here. if the interviewer is concerned about the size of the resulting file, the solution may be written in any language. the question does not specify if the interviewer wants compact output or compact code...*

Comment: I don't think this qualifies. Most likely the order is important (though, not specified in the question). Otherwise you wouldn't need to save them at all.

Comment: python is completely unimportant here, but I was interviewed for python position. Voted up.

Comment: @Bobby: then, given the list of numbers in a variable called `numbers`, use `f.write(str(numbers))`. the code is thus very compact, and the numbers are written to the file, which is what the interviewer wanted, and loading works the same. (i have to admit that this file format is pretty inefficient)

Comment: @Bobby: but then the resulting file is not compact at all, defeating the last point of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I would only write the start and end of the given range, in this case 1 and 1,000,000, because nowhere has the interviewer mentioned order is important.

Answer (score 0):

`What is the most compact way to write 1,000,000 ints (0, 1, 2...) to file using Python without zipping etc`

If you interpret the `1,000,000` ints as "I didn't specify that they have to be different", you can just use a for loop to write `0` one million times.

Comment: I'd just specify that the character "!" represents one million zeros in a row, and write that into the file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe they meant something like this
[pythonic-way-to-convert-a-list-of-integers-into-a-string-of-comma-separated-range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430231) but then you said that consecutive sequences are rare, so perhaps not